# Parsing issues in SOAP response using NSXML parser in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, soap, nsxmlparser

I have used the SOAP webservice in my app. I have sent the SOAP request to server and the getting the resulst in the XML formats. I am using NSXML Parser for parsing the data.

I want to get the data "true", when i have tried to parse the content application get crashed, I couldn't parsed that data.

```
<ServiceFinalResult>
<Response  xmlns="http://aaaa.com/test/schemas/services/myaccounts/data/_1_0">
  true
</Response> 
</ServiceFinalResult>
```

So please help me out.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/exl0v00mmqss1n5gxnpea

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/b430ecq5cwxbedhohy8y0w

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/pgi9tzmatbpocmfkkfviba

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    "<name>testName</name>\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n";

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:webServiceUrl];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];              
[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:yourSoapAction forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[req setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];  
NSData *webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```